# Hotmail/Live.com mailto: URL no longer working. Is there a new format?

Tags: outlook.com

Hotmail/Live.com changed their `mailto:` email handler. It used to be:

```
https://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s
```

Where the `%s` gets replaced with `mailto:email@blah.com` by the browser when you click on `mailto:` links.

So going to `https://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=mailto:rawr@gmail.com` will open the compose mail page pre-populated with `rawr@gmail.com` in the `To` field. However this is no longer working and I can't figure out the current one, can you please help me?

Comment: Craigslist appears to using: `https://mail.live.com/default.aspx?rru=compose&to=TO&subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY` which is no longer working either.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a compose link that works right now:

`https://outlook.live.com/owa/#subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY&to=TO@EXAMPLE.COM&path=%2fmail%2faction%2fcompose`

This then has the following compose screen:

[image]

Source: [answers.microsoft.com: Outlook.com compose link?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/outlookcom-compose-link/88f2d397-d7ca-4db2-b6a4-163a754074d7) where the answer has a link to blu182.mail.live.com which redirects to the link I've included here.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for sharing this! However it doesn't work in Firefox. Firefox prefixes the email with `mailto:` so in my test it was `mailto:TO@EXAMPLE.COM` which caused it to not load :(

Comment: You must have an extension installed that is doing that.  Firefox shouldn't be touching https URLs embedded in a href.   It works fine in Firefox for me.

Comment: Ah I am adding custom mailto handler via options page - http://i.imgur.com/XZDYpJz.png - I install custom handler with - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mailtowebmails/ - many users are trying to find outlook that works, I seriously appreicate your effort to help us! I reached out to microsfot support many times but they dont help :(